# Comparing two strings on Android

Tags: android

When comparing two strings in if-else condition, the wrong branch is executed. I have `s1 = "failure"` and I compare it with `ss` for executing, but it goes to the else branch. Why, when the condition is satisfied?

```
public class cabbookingconfirmation extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cabbbookingconfirmation);
        String ss = Activity1.getData();
        String s1 = "failure";
        Log.i("tag..........", ss);
        if (ss.equals(s1)) {
             Log.i("saurabh..........","trivedi....");
        } else {
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.details);
            tv.setText("Dear Gaurav....," +
                "Your cab has been booked. " +
                "Please refer to your planner " +
                "for details.Have a safe trip!");
            tv.setBackgroundColor(111);
        }
    }
}
```

activity1.java is below

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity
{
    public static String getData() {
        String responceid = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://qrrency.com/mobile/j2me/cab/BookCab.php?bookingid=666");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            int m = 0;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String str1 = " ";
            while ((m = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                       buffer.append((char)m);
                       str1 = str1 + (char)m;
                       responceid = str1;
            }

            Log.i("Line----saurabh trivedi---,------,,--", responceid);

            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return responceid;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to print both the strings namely `s1` and `ss`.

Comment: Are you sure `Activity1.getData()` returns a real string ? Can we see source code for this method ?

Comment: so, your strings are not equal. And ss is not "failure", it equals Activity1.getData(). as pankaj suggested make case insensetive comparation (compareToIgnoreCase)

Comment: @Ocus i add Activity1.getData() pls see it in my code...thanks for agin appresiating me in advanse

Comment: `responseid` clearly starts with a space... `String str1 = " ";` then `str1=str1+(char)m;responceid   =str1;`. so `" failure"` will never equals `"failure"`...

Comment: @OcuS ya u r right....thanks for help...v v thanks for help me

Answer (score -1):

I dont really know Andriod SDK

in .net

```
 if (ss.equals(s1))
```

Should work perfectly! Maybe here ss.equals does not test the string? or the string returned is in another format or whitespace?

Try and use

```
(string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2))
```

edit- removed (ss == s1) - not correct original answer

That is java syntax and should work- if not.. then there is something different in the two stings and you would have to decode them and see where the difference is

by the way- what does this do

```
  Log.i("tag..........",ss);
```

are you sure that is not affecting ss in some way? its right before the if and after the declaration

Comment: -1 Not really a good advice. == compares the references and not the content. and Log.i() does not modify the string but prints it to the Logcat.

Comment: Yea - sorry! your original code is correct  string1.equals(string2) but you can also use (string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2))